# Robocopy mirror to Samba keeps rewriting files

Tags: samba, robocopy

We have a Samba share to which I am copying files with robocopy /mir.  Problem is the next time I try and sync that with robocopy /mir it copies all files again even though they haven't changed.  I can't see why robocopy should be detecting all these files as changed when they haven't been.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
  Nick

Comment: Check if the times matches with the local one for the remote file after the first copy run.

Comment: Yep file times match but directories are replaced with the time of the copy.

Comment: Now found a fix for that /dcopy:T but robocopy still detects all as Modified.

Comment: Even checked permissions and they are the same, except for the 'Inherited from' description which is slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

If the original folder is formatted NTFS and the destination is EXT3 or EXT4 try the option /FFT (assume FAT File Times (2-second granularity)). NTFS and EXT* record time with different precision and that throws off the time match in robocopy.

Comment: Tried that but no difference.  Currently using '/FFT /DCOPY:DAT /MIR' but all files still detecting as Modified

Comment: Any update on this ?